# Bigquery cumulative sum with condition

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to get cumsum with the condition that if the current value in the row is less than the cumsum in this row, then this value will not be added to cumsum

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this in pure SQL you would need a recursive CTE, which bigquery does not support.

[This workaround](https://dwgeek.com/bigquery-recursive-query-alternative-example.html/) does not perform well, but if you only have thousands of records then you'll be okay.

```
DECLARE current_year int64 default 2015;
DECLARE cumsum int64 default 0;
DECLARE accrual int64;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE input
AS
select 2015 year, 1 accrual
    union all select 2016, 5
    union all select 2017, 4
    union all select 2018, 9
    union all select 2019, 14
    union all select 2020, 27;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE output 
(
    year int64,
    accrual int64,
    cumsum int64
);

WHILE EXISTS (
    SELECT year
    FROM input
    where year = current_year
)
DO
    SET accrual = ( 
        SELECT accrual
        FROM input
        where year = current_year
    );

    if accrual >= cumsum THEN
        set cumsum = accrual + cumsum;
    END IF;

    INSERT INTO output 
    VALUES (current_year, accrual, cumsum);

    SET current_year = current_year + 1;
END WHILE;

-- Display
SELECT  * from output order by year
```